# Sharepoint 2013 include javascript on homepage with CustomAction

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I deploy a sandboxed solution to a Sharepoint 2013 site with an `CustomAction` setting to include my javascript file on every page like this:

```
<CustomAction ScriptSrc="MyScriptUrl.js" Location="ScriptLink" Sequence="10000">
```

This works fine on all pages the page is rendered like this and my script link is included:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/1033/initstrings.js?rev=uNmvBiHdrBzcPQzXRpm%2FnQ%3D%3D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js?rev=vtrc0n3sjgxKB4WQrCEeaA%3D%3D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/MyApp/MyScriptUrl.js"></script>
...
```

But on the home page (start.aspx) my link is missing and the js includes are quite different:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js?rev=zwpf9CD1m7am6imImmQglQ%3D%3D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=nnhGXhlC0O1qfk6HXinkGyT_1TJisFpYK2ABJoGzI-IJfbkEQ8O-FNAr_1TgMft0D4TC2OewVZXiRooP_-SU74hHHu0AiGA4sSA3rrm1cvMqv3QRvFv8PafLyLDxWfN1O4qPFJXWfAf3avBHVS0HiXP55em_jNSsNMvRj1GJO4rjzyxg1vBi7IfXVHSWNBK60&amp;t=6119e399"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/blank.js?rev=ZaOXZEobVwykPO9g8hq%2F8A%3D%3D"></script>
...
```

(Note: Of course there are more JS files but I just wanted to show that there are different includes)

**What am I doing wrong?**